# How to preserve argument/parameter registers under x86-64?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, 64-bit

The [System V AMD64 ABI call convention](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) is mandated thus:

> Registers `%rbp`, `%rbx` and `%r12` through `%r15` “belong” to the calling
>   function and the called function is required to preserve their values.
>   In other words, a called function must preserve these registers’
>   values for its caller. Remaining registers “belong” to the called
>   function. If a calling function wants to preserve such a register
>   value across a function call, it must save the value in its local
>   stack frame.

For example, given this code:

```
void f1(const int i, const double j, const char * k)
{
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    printf("j = %g\n", j);
    printf("k = %s\n", k);
}
```

The assembly representation is:

```
f1():
  4004f4:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004f5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004f8:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  4004fc:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  4004ff:   f2 0f 11 45 f0          movsd  %xmm0,-0x10(%rbp)
  400504:   48 89 75 e8             mov    %rsi,-0x18(%rbp)
  400508:   b8 70 06 40 00          mov    $0x400670,%eax
  40050d:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
  400510:   89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
  400512:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400515:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40051a:   e8 d1 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  40051f:   b8 78 06 40 00          mov    $0x400678,%eax
  400524:   f2 0f 10 45 f0          movsd  -0x10(%rbp),%xmm0
  400529:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40052c:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  400531:   e8 ba fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  400536:   b8 80 06 40 00          mov    $0x400680,%eax
  40053b:   48 8b 55 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rdx
  40053f:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
  400542:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400545:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40054a:   e8 a1 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  40054f:   c9                      leaveq 
  400550:   c3                      retq
```

In this instance, the parameters have been passed in `%edi`, `%xmm0` and `%rsi`. The call convention states that these registers "belong" to the called function and this means `f1` has no obligation to preserve their values. In fact, `%edi`, `%xmm0` and `%rsi` are all trashed on the following lines:

```
400510: 89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
400512: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
..
400524: f2 0f 10 45 f0          movsd  -0x10(%rbp),%xmm0
```

I want to preserve all argument registers. The documentation states the value can be saved on the local stack which I have tried as follows:

```
void f1(const int i, const double j, const char * k)
{
    uint32_t edi;
    __asm ("movl %%edi, %0;" : "=r" ( edi ));

    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    printf("j = %g\n", j);
    printf("k = %s\n", k);

    __asm ("movl %0, %%edi;" : "=d"( edi ));
}
```

This generates the following:

```
f1():
  4004f4:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004f5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004f8:   53                      push   %rbx
  4004f9:   48 83 ec 38             sub    $0x38,%rsp
  4004fd:   89 7d dc                mov    %edi,-0x24(%rbp)
  400500:   f2 0f 11 45 d0          movsd  %xmm0,-0x30(%rbp)
  400505:   48 89 75 c8             mov    %rsi,-0x38(%rbp)
  400509:   89 fb                   mov    %edi,%ebx
  40050b:   89 5d ec                mov    %ebx,-0x14(%rbp)
  40050e:   b8 80 06 40 00          mov    $0x400680,%eax
  400513:   8b 55 dc                mov    -0x24(%rbp),%edx
  400516:   89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
  400518:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40051b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400520:   e8 cb fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  400525:   b8 88 06 40 00          mov    $0x400688,%eax
  40052a:   f2 0f 10 45 d0          movsd  -0x30(%rbp),%xmm0
  40052f:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400532:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  400537:   e8 b4 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  40053c:   b8 90 06 40 00          mov    $0x400690,%eax
  400541:   48 8b 55 c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rdx
  400545:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
  400548:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40054b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400550:   e8 9b fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  400555:   89 d7                   mov    %edx,%edi
  400557:   89 d3                   mov    %edx,%ebx
  400559:   89 5d ec                mov    %ebx,-0x14(%rbp)
  40055c:   48 83 c4 38             add    $0x38,%rsp
  400560:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  400561:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400562:   c3                      retq
```

This does not appear to be restoring the value of `%edi`. What is the correct way for preserving all the argument/parameter registers?

Comment: Have you checked the resulting assembly and verified in a debugger that the correct value is restored? Inline assembly can be a nasty beast.

Comment: @NiklasB.: I did look at the disassembly, but it was quite verbose to post. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/HUexwViQ I wasn't sure what was wrong after looking at it. The segfault occurs after doing the first `printf`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that. I don't think you can play with the stack like you want to do. What you probably want to do is to declare local variables or a local buffer and use those to hold the register values.

Comment: @NiklasB.: I've just added the extended asm I used to try to do just that.

Comment: I don't see it restoring the value. Maybe the loophole optimizer is stripping your restore because it knows that RDI can be clobbered?

Comment: @NiklasB.: Perhaps so, but I am compiling with -O0.

Answer (score 5):

You can't mix C and asm like this. In particular, executing an isolated push or pop instruction in inline assembly will horribly break things; any given inline assembly block must have a net offset of 0 on the stack pointer.

Really, the ABI document is rather irrelevant to the use of inline asm. For that, you need to follow the GCC inline asm contract of documenting which registers you use for input and output and what's in the clobber list. The ABI is relevant if you're writing entire functions in assembler (in a `.s` file not a `.c` file).

Comment: So this is dealt with in the extended asm code (which I guess is why it does not segfault). Do you know why in that case `%edi` is not restored? I linked to the ABI document to give context of what I'm trying to do in case there is a better way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: The ABI governs the contract for function calls between the caller and the callee. There is no function call in inline ASM.

Comment: Now, if you wanted to make a function call from within your asm block to an extern function written in C that's compiled to match the ABI contract, then you'd have to follow the ABI rules for a caller...

Comment: I want the C function to preserve the argument registers. I simply used ASM because that is what I supposed might be the best way to achieve this. Perhaps there is something unclear in the question but we seem to be on different pages. Is there anything I could clarify that could help this?

Comment: No, there is no way. By the time you get the any code (asm or C) in your function body, arbitrary code generated by the compiler (often referred to collectively as *function prologue*) has already run and potentially clobbered any registers which are not specified by the ABI as callee-saved. If you need additional registers to be saved - this would only be necessary or useful when the function is called from your own asm! - then you need to write a wrapper function in asm that saves registers on the stack before calling your function.